# How to write combine csv in memory using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a process that reads some data and generate and write csv files using pandas. I am saving it to my local machine with this -> df.to_csv('somefilepath/file_name'.csv). but instead of saving each file in the local machine, i want to keep the file in memory and later I want to concatenate those csv into a new dataframe as such ->  df. = pd.concat([pd.read_csv()]). any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

some_path = 'some_path'
files = os.listdir(some_path)

for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(some_path, file)):
        f = open(os.path.join(some_path, file),'r')

        for x in f:
            //do some ETL 
            df = pd.DataFrame(file_content)

            df.to_csv('somefilepath/file_name'.csv)
            
            #df. = pd.concat()

        f.close()
```

Comment: Why don't you want to just keep them in memory as DataFrames?

Comment: @ThePhoton - thanks. i am new to python and all. so would that generating a new dataframe variable inside a loop and later combining it?

Comment: Or accumulate them into a big DataFrame as you go along?

Comment: @ThePhoton - if you don't mind, could you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save the individual data sets in memory as DataFrames, and concatenate them at the end:

```
frames = []
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(some_path, file)):
        f = open(os.path.join(some_path, file),'r')

        for x in f:
            //do some ETL 
            frames.append(pd.DataFrame(file_content))

        f.close()
df = pd.DataFrame.concat(frames)
```

Aside: you should also learn the `with open(...) as f:` syntax to be sure your file gets closed even if the loop is exited through an exception.